# Calculate the area of geographical coordinates in solidity

Tags: solidity, truffle

I am programming a map-based dapp. Since Float variables are not supported, I have to store the lat/lon (polygon's coordinates) as String or UINT. I want to calculate the area of the selected polygon. But I do not know how to do it.
In JavaScript, I used the [turfjs](https://turfjs.org) library. Please help me.

Comment: Is it really needed to compute it on chain? Did you consider using fixed point?

Comment: I can not calculate this value on the client side. The client should not be trusted. The user (hacker) may send incorrect information. @Ismael

Comment: The EVM is quite limited on resources I'd suggest to consider changing the protocol for a more decentralized approach. For example the Dark Forest game uses ZKSnarks https://blog.zkga.me/intro-to-zksnarks.